# Correctly implementing Tasks in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await, task

I'm looking for some advice on getting to grips with `Task`s in WPF and was wondering if anyone could have a look over my code and point out what I'm doing incorrectly?

Basically the application takes a postcode from the UI which is used to instantiate a `Task` service which will get Longitude/Latitude which can be accessed via the instance for use in another service or the UI itself.

I think I may have a race condition which I'm looking to correct as when `ResultTextBlock.Text` is set it's a zero, but stepping through instantiation I see those values set.

Any advice on `Task` implementation and wiring would be greatly appreciated.

### Service Code

```
class PostcodeService
{
    string _result;
    string _postcode;

    HttpResponseMessage _response;        
    RootObject rootObject;

    public double Latitude { get; private set; }
    public double Longitude { get; private set; }        

    public PostcodeService(string postcode)
    {
        this._postcode = postcode;
        rootObject = new RootObject();
    }

    public async Task<string> GetLongLatAsync()
    {        
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/" + this._postcode);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));  

            try
            {
                _response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
                if(_response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //cast result into model and then set long/lat properties which can then be used in the UI
                    _result = await _response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                     

                    rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(_result);
                    Longitude = Double.Parse(rootObject.result.longitude.ToString());
                    Latitude =  Double.Parse(rootObject.result.latitude.ToString());
                }                                      
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.ToString();
            }
        }

        TaskCompletionSource<string> tc = new TaskCompletionSource<string>(_result);

        return tc.ToString();
    }
}
```

### UI Code

```
private void PostcodeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _clearStatus();

    if (_validatePostcode())
    {
        Task T1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            // get long lat from api
            _postcode = new PostcodeService(PostcodeTextBox.Text);
            await _postcode.GetLongLatAsync();
        });

        //Race condition?
        ResultTextBlock.Text = _postcode.Latitude.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be better fit for CodeReview?

Comment: My understanding is that CodeReview is for code that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `GetLongLatAsync()` method should return a `string`:

```
public async Task<string> GetLongLatAsync()
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/" + this._postcode);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        _response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
        string result = null;
        if (_response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //cast result into model and then set long/lat properties which can then be used in the UI
            result = await _response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(_result);
            Longitude = Double.Parse(rootObject.result.longitude.ToString());
            Latitude = Double.Parse(rootObject.result.latitude.ToString());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

...and you should simply await `GetLongLatAsync()` in the UI:

```
private async void PostcodeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _clearStatus();
    if (_validatePostcode())
    {
        // get long lat from api
        _postcode = new PostcodeService(PostcodeTextBox.Text);
        string result = await _postcode.GetLongLatAsync();
        ResultTextBlock.Text = result.ToString();
    }
}
```

You don't need to use a `TaskCompletionSource` nor start a new `Task` to call an async method.

Comment: Thanks, I had a suspicion that Task wrapping was unnecessary.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry - Closed!

Answer (score 2):

Event handlers allow async void to be used

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

```
private async void PostcodeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    _clearStatus();

    if (_validatePostcode()) {
        // get long lat from api
        _postcode = new PostcodeService(PostcodeTextBox.Text);
        await _postcode.GetLongLatAsync(); //Offload UI thread
        //Back on UI thread
        ResultTextBlock.Text = _postcode.Latitude.ToString();
    }
}
```

Secondly to avoid thread exhaustion, create a single `HttpClient` instead of creating and disposing it when you need to perform this action

Reference [You're using HttpClient wrong](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

The design of the service should be refactored into separate concerns

```
public class Location {
    public Location(double lat, double lon) {
        Latitude = lat;
        Longitude = lon;
    }
    public double Latitude { get; private set; }
    public double Longitude { get; private set; }    
}

public class PostcodeService {
    private static Lazy<HttpClient> client;
    static PostcodeService() {
        client = new Lazy<HttpClient>(() => {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            return httpClient;
        });
    }

    public async Task<Location> GetLongLatAsync(string postcode) {}
        var response = await client.Value.GetAsync(postcode);
        if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            //cast result into model and then set long/lat properties which can then be used in the UI
            var rootObject = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<RootObject>();
            var Longitude = Double.Parse(rootObject.result.longitude.ToString());
            var Latitude =  Double.Parse(rootObject.result.latitude.ToString());
            var result = new Location(Latitude, Longitude);
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The event handler can now be refactored to

```
private async void PostcodeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    _clearStatus();

    if (_validatePostcode()) {
        // get long lat from api
        var service = new PostcodeService();
        var location = await service.GetLongLatAsync(PostcodeTextBox.Text); //Offload UI thread
        //Back on UI thread
        if(location != null) {

            ResultTextBlock.Text = location.Latitude.ToString();
        } else {
            //Some message here
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: There should also be only one instance of `PostcodeService`

Comment: @Ackdari agreed. With the static constructor and httpclient it doesn't matter much. The class can be abstracted to allow injection where it is needed

Comment: Thanks for the links and the refactor. I'll certainly go about implementing a static HttpClient